# Package update error, but package seems to be installed

Tags: updates

Every time I update my system I get the following error. I use Ubuntu 12.04
[image]

There is no updates, if I run the Update Manager again. So I assume that the updates are installed. The complete error code is

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 425052 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace julia 0.3.4~precise1 (using .../julia_0.3.5~precise1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement julia ...
Preparing to replace cpio 2.11-7ubuntu3 (using .../cpio_2.11-7ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement cpio ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
Setting up fgfs-base (2.4.0-1) ...
Moving /usr/share/games/FlightGear to /usr/share/games/flightgear...
cp: cannot stat `/usr/share/games/FlightGear/*': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing fgfs-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fgfs-atlas:
 fgfs-atlas depends on fgfs-base (>= 1.0.0); however:
  Package fgfs-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing fgfs-atlas (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up julia (0.3.5~precise1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Setting up cpio (2.11-7ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fgfs-base
 fgfs-atlas
Error in function: 
Setting up fgfs-base (2.4.0-1) ...
Moving /usr/share/games/FlightGear to /usr/share/games/flightgear...
cp: cannot stat `/usr/share/games/FlightGear/*': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing fgfs-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fgfs-atlas:
 fgfs-atlas depends on fgfs-base (>= 1.0.0); however:
  Package fgfs-base is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing fgfs-atlas (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

But how do i get rid of the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a confirmed bug-you can check the details here:https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fgfs-base/+bug/942886

This bug was fixed in the package `fgfs-base - 2.6.0-1`. Maybe your ubuntu distribution is too outdated if you still can't update it.